# Circular dependency Angular

Tags: angular

I have component and a service, I have referenced the service in the component and vice versa and I get a circular dependency ( as expected), but when I change the absolute path of the component to relative path in the service the circular dependency is resolved, how does changing the path ( from “@project/component” to “../folderpath/component” in the service file ) resolve the issue ?

Comment: how does `a circular dependency` manifest itself and how do you know it's resolved?

Comment: Can you update your question with code for more details?

Comment: A side question that appears to me is why a service would need to reference a component? It should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

What is a circular dependency? Import path from one file to another and from another to one.

It seems your component has entry point in alias `@project/component` as well as the service. That's the reason why you have to use relative path in this case. Then your component only imports the service and the service doesn't know about component (have to).